# Alternative page layouts for Chatter Mobile

Tags: chatter, mobile, page-layout

I am customising a version of Salesforce, and our 'Contacts' have quite a lot of fields associated with them. While this looks fine on a Desktop, it is a bit overwhelming to users on the Chatter Mobile iOS app.

I can see how to create a more simple input form using Publisher Actions, but this does not let me change the fields available when viewing or editing a contact, nor does it override the main 'New Contact' button in the app.

Is there a way to create a new Page Layout that is used only in the Chatter Mobile app?

Thank you in advance for any help.